# Print unicode characters using format

Tags: python, unicode

I have this code:

```
print u'\u2660'
```

it prints: ♠

but if I do this:

```
sym = '\u2660'
print u'{0}'.format(sym)
```

or

```
sym = '\u2660'
print u'%s' % (sym)
```

it prints: '\u2660' , why? How can I use `format` to print a unicode symbol?

Comment: Prepend `u` as you did for the first statement: `sym = u'\u2660'`

Comment: `'\u2660'` (without the `u` prefix) is equivalent to `'\\u2660'`.